# How to display code-block in Plone restructuredtext content

Tags: plone, restructuredtext, pygments

I'm trying to support syntax highlighting in the cms Plone.

The context: we are using a base Plone install. Add a document and change type from HTML to Restructuredtext then add a simple code block:

```
.. code-block :: python

from plone import api
```

Save the document and you have the following html code block

```
<pre class="code python literal-block">
    <span class="keyword namespace">from</span> <span class="name namespace">plone</span> <span class="keyword namespace">import</span> <span class="name">api</span>
</pre>
```

So the transforms happens but the classes uses here doesn't fit with any CSS I have found on Internet.

debugging this show me docutils.utils.code_analyser.py Lexer.**init** is called with tokennames='long' instead of tokennames='short'

This is why the class names are long. I have two options:

- finding how to change it ? (without just monkey patching but the call chain is so big...)
- finding how to generate with pygments the long version

Comment: Hmm. That looks like ReST, not Markdown. But the html doesn't look like pygments, which is what docutils uses. *confused*.